# Recover ansible-vault password in case password is forgotten

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible-vault to set password protect var/main.yml file. 
   Now I can push my source code in source control system. After that deploys in production server. Suppose somebody manipulate the password or  forgot the password. Is there any way to recover ansible-vault 
   password or set the new password again without asking the old password?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you brute force the password there is no way to recover it.

I suggest you use a password manager to store your password and share the password database within your organization. For example, you could store the password in a password service which has email or SMS reset option to recover the user account, though **this might not be very good idea for high security environments**.

Comment: Thanks for Answer , Initially I am thinking to implement zookeeper for configuration management (to keep password safely) After that I realized It's burden for us because it need odd number of dedicated server. So I dropped that Idea, I already wrote ansible-playbook for server installation/configuration. I need to think how to use ansible-vault because it is very light weight and easy to implement. Do you have any other advise to keep  password secure in source control system and recovery of password in case of external damage

Comment: Personally I keep KeePassX database in a Dropbox synced folder: https://www.keepassx.org/ - it has client application to all platforms (inc. Android) and is 100% open source so it is a safe bet. Of course, you need to store the master password of the password manager somewhere, so it is kind of moving the problem around.